# Automapping in ASP.Net Core 2.1 Project

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I have custom field in my UserIdentity Table called "Name". The Name field would hold the name of a user, who has registered.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {       
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool CanNotify { get; set; }

    }
```

I have another table called Post has a field "AuthorName"

```
public class Post
    { 
        public Instant Published { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; } 
}
```

When I create/post a blog, I want AuthorName should be the one who has signed in, which means AuthorName should be associated with Name from UserManager table, who is currently signed in.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    cmd = _mapper.Map(User, cmd);
}

public class Mapper : Profile
{
   public Mapper()
   {
       CreateMap<ClaimsPrincipal, CreatePostCommand>(MemberList.None)
                   .ForMember(d => d.UserId, m => m.MapFrom(s => 
                   Guid.Parse(s.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))))
                .ForMember(d => d.Name, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Identity.AuthorName));

   }
}
```

Above code works fine, but I don't want Identity Name to be mapped, rather it should map from UserManager table, I have tried many logics but did not work, Let me paste one of those:-

```
CreateMap<ClaimsPrincipal, CreatePostCommand>(MemberList.Source)
              .ForMember(d => d.UserId, m => m.MapFrom(s => Guid.Parse(s.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))))
              .ForMember(d => d.Name, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.FindFirst(_userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.AuthorName)));
```

But the above mapping rules giving me an error

> "User" is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Answer (score 0):

As you may be able to see from the blue color of "User", "User" is interpreted by the compiler as a Type (or possibly a method, but the compiler error indicates that it is interpreted as type, which is also logical, since there is a type User). This can simply be since you have a class User.

The question is: which object/variable are you trying to pass to _userManager.GetUserAsync() ? rename that variable from User to something else (like LocalUser or myUser or whatever), that should fix the problem.